# How to set variable value while publishing the build artifacts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Below is the code snippet that I used to read the AppName from `appsettings.json` file.

Startup.cs → ConfigureServices()

```
services.Configure<CustomConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("CustomConfig"));
services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CustomConfig>>().Value);
```

CustomConfig.cs

```
public class CustomConfig
{
   public string AppName { get; set; }
}
```

But my requirement is, `AppName` will change based on different customers but at the same time that should not be maintained in the `appsettings.json` file.

*So my question is*, how to set a variable value while publishing the application, instead of reading it from configuration files/environment level variables?

Comment: This is too broad. You can read it from virtually *any* other source. A file, a database, a voice recognition part of your program listening for voices of middle aged females speaking mandarin with a Russian accent... *anything*. It's your job to decide. when you made a decision, feel free to ask a specific question about the implementation.

Comment: @nvoigt is it possible to read it from assembly itself?

Comment: I mean, instead of hard coding the value in a class file, is it possible to assign the value to a property, while publishing the application?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in the publish process. You could have different build configurations and change code according to that though.

Comment: I would question your requirement though. Why not appsetting.json? There are valid reasons why not, but as long as you don't know those reasons, picking a random alternative is not going to make it better. It might have the same qualities the appsettings.json was ruled out and you are back where you started.

Comment: @nvoigt It's because we don't like our customer to change the AppName once we shipped; Moreover, we have to ship the same code to N number of customers so we could not hardcode the value in a class file.

Comment: hm... if it's "secure enough" to have it in the assembly, you could create build configurations that do that. Just create one per customer and `#ifdef` the variable assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core doesn't use build configurations, and the published code is not specific to any sort of environment. *That's by design.* Your best bet is to probably assign each customer their own environment. Then, you could have customer-specific appsettings.json files: `appsettings.Customer1.json`, `appsettings.Customer2.json`, etc.

The actual environment that's utilized is controlled by the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, typically, though there's other ways to specify the environment. Depending on how you're ultimately hosting this, the best method for doing that differs. If you're running in a container or something like Azure App Services, then just stick with the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, which can be easily set per running instance.

If you're starting the app from the command line directly, you can pass the environment via the `--environment` command line argument when calling running `dotnet`.

If you're hosting these all on the same IIS server, for instance, then you can add it to the Web.config, but you'd probably want a more robust solution than that. If you create publish profiles for each customer, then you can add the the following to each publish profile (`.pubxml`):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnvironmentName>Customer1</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then, when you publish with that particular profile, that environment will be added to the `Web.config` for you automatically. However, this is just a more automated way of getting the value in the `Web.config`. There's no functional difference in the actual published app, and you could easily go in after the fact and switch the environment to something else.